# Plain Javascript (no JQuery) to load a php file into a div

Tags: javascript, function

Hi I don't know javascript but I am required to use it in one of my templates. I was googling around and found a solution whic is like this:

**My Index.php file.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML="<img src='loadingImage.gif'>";
if(XMLHttpRequest) var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
else var x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
x.open("GET", "other_content_1.php", true);
x.send("");
x.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(x.readyState == 4){
        if(x.status==200) document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML = x.responseText;
        else document.getElementById("aside").innerHTML = "Error loading document";
        }
    }
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="aside">This is aside</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My other_content_1.php file**

```
<div id='other-content-1'>
<?php echo 'This text is loading via php command'; ?>
</div>
```

As this is the only Javascript function in my site I see no reason to load additional JQuery for it. I am sure there must be a way to do this with plain JavaScript / ajax without the need to load JQuery. Can anybody suggest the correct syntax to do so?

I want to happen asynchronously while the page continues to load.

Comment: That jQuery is probably cached in your browser anyway, so..why bother?
Just google pure javascript AJAX tutorial

Comment: Really, why would you NOT want to use jQuery? The  (great) answer below works but compared it to the jquery implementation.

Comment: I fully agree the rationale not to use jQuery, rock on! What browsers do you have to support? Some of these answers are great but in practice treat a lot of IE5 and IE6 edge cases where most sites only support IE8+ today.

Comment: Bother because performance is important?

Comment: Hi guys! As mentioned by @heytools very correctly. Performance is the key to this template that is why I want to keep the size to minimal. Thanks for going through my question.

Comment: @Benjamin I need to support IE6+ and yes I am facing the same problem with the below answers. IE6 and IE7 are not getting it right. It gets stuck the the loading.gif state. Rest all browsers are running fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function(){
aside = document.getElementById("aside");
aside.innerHTML="<img src='loadingImage.gif'>";
if(XMLHttpRequest) var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
else var x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
x.open("GET", "other_content_1.php", true);
x.send();
x.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(x.readyState == 4){
        if(x.status == 200) aside.innerHTML = x.responseText;
        else aside.innerHTML = "Error loading document";
        }
    }
}
```

And it **is** cross browser compatible, you never need the extra 32KB just to make a simple function supported cross browser.

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't work in there, maybe try x.send(""); instead of x.send(); ?

Comment: Try replacing the 3 "aside.innerHTML =" with "aside.firstChild.data ="

Comment: So put back to innerHTML... and try x.open("GET", "other_content_1.php", 1); OR x.open("GET", "other_content_1.php"); instead of x.open("GET", "other_content_1.php", true);

Comment: I guess that would perfectly make the subject of a new question in SO, something like: "Which part of my code isn't supported by IE 6&7?"

Comment: Ok here you go. Except IE6 it works in all browsers. As suggested by you, I will open a new question right away for IE6 issue.

Answer (score 7):

from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/ , using plain XHR (XmlHttpRequest)

```
function loadPage() {    
    var ajaxRequest;  

    try{
       // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
       ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }catch (e){
       // Internet Explorer Browsers
       try{
          ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
       }catch (e) {
          try{
              ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }catch (e){
              // Something went wrong
              alert("Your browser broke!");
              return false;
          }
       }
     }

     ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
       if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
          var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
          ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
       }
     }


     ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php", true);
     ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

loadPage();
```

Comment: syntax errors mean that you have some character where isnt supposed to be. the above code doesnt have any syntax errors ( i just pasted in my javascript console and it ran without error) so you must have copied it or typed it wrong. Make sure it looks like this without any extra characters near the return false line.

Comment: make sure to change `ajax-example.php` to the page you are trying to get, and change `document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');` to have the id of the element you are trying to put the html in.

Comment: this code is meant to be run in a function ill edit my answer to reflect

Comment: Sorry but this is a copy/paste from Internet, a general AJAX case that doesn't include many of the features required by the OP (waiting for the document to get ready, the loading image, the real tags IDs..), my answer was written especially for this question, and it's not getting any attention?

Comment: All he asked was for the correct syntax, and the code he showed implied it was just an example of what he seen on whatever page he was looking at, and not the code he was working with. @VikramRao, if you are using new code edit your answer to reflect the code you are currently using, as i have no idea what you are doing with loading.gif.

Comment: @VikramRao, edit your answer to include both the javascript and your html

Comment: @Patrick edited my Question with full code. I used both your and 'heytools' code but both are getting stuck at loadingImage.gif stage in IE 6 and IE7 however all other browsers run fine.

Comment: what do you mean by getting "stuck" is it erroring out? if so with what error message